# ExtJS - GridPanel with Ext.ux.grid.FilterRow and Ext.PagingToolbar

Tags: gridview, extjs, filtering

I've add "FilterRow" plugin to a GridPanel with PagingToolBar. The Grid works good except for this issue:
if I try to sort or filter a column the grid generate this POST variables --> sort, dir and all my filters enabled.
Instead if I try to go to next page this POST variables --> sort, dir, start, limit.
If I try to scroll pages I lose filter's variables previously posted.
This is my code:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){            

    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
      url: "get-data-for-grid.php",
      root: "rows",
      id:'id',   
      totalProperty:'totalCount',      
      remoteSort: true,
      sortInfo: {
            field: 'genere',
            direction: 'ASC'
      },      
      autoDestroy: true,
      fields: [
         {name: 'scheda'},
         {name: 'topic'},
         {name: 'genere'},
         {name: 'specie'},
         {name: 'autore'},
         {name: 'comme'},
         {name: 'famiglia'},
         {name: 'nomecomune'},
         {name: 'datains'}
      ]
    });

    var filterRow = new Ext.ux.grid.FilterRow({
      autoFilter: false,
      listeners: {
        change: function(data) {
          store.load({
            params: data
          });
        }
      }
    });       

    // create the Grid
      var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: store,
        loadMask: true,
        columns: [
            {id:'scheda', header: "Scheda", width: 73, align: 'center', sortable: false, renderer: scheda, dataIndex: 'scheda'},                    
            {id:'genere', header: "Genere", width: 130, renderer: gen, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'genere', filter:{ }},
            {id:'specie', header: "Specie", width: 150, sortable: true, renderer: spe, dataIndex: 'specie', filter:{ }},
            {id:'autore', header: "Autore", width: 150, sortable: true, renderer: all, dataIndex: 'autore', filter:{ }},
            {id:'famiglia', header: "Famiglia", width: 150, sortable: true, renderer: fam, dataIndex: 'famiglia', filter:{ }},
            {id:'nomecomune', header: "Nome Comune", width: 190, sortable: true, renderer: all, dataIndex: 'nomecomune', filter:{ }},
            {id:'datains', header: "Aggior.", width: 75, sortable: true, renderer: data, dataIndex: 'datains'}   
        ],
        highlightClasses: {
          ASC:  'x-custom-sort-asc'
          // DESC stays at default = x-ux-col-sort-desc
        },        
        bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
            pageSize: 15,
            store: store,
            displayInfo: true
        }),    
        plugins: [filterRow],

        height:660,
        width:1010,
        frame:true,                
        title:
        '<div align="center"><img src="images/testata_micologia.jpg" alt="" height="68" width="974" border="0"></div>',
        renderTo: "grid-example"
      });          

    grid.render('grid-example');

    store.load({params:{start:0, limit:15}});
});
```

How can "Ext.PagingToolbar" generate filter's POST variables previously posted (genere, specie, autore,.. in my example)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to persist your filter parameters you have to use the [**`baseParams`**](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store&member=baseParams) property instead of the `params` property of the store.

The *baseParams* property will persist across all the calls to the `load` method.

So I would implement this in your *change* listener of your `FilterRow`:

```
    change: function(data) {
      Ext.apply(store.baseParams, data);
      store.load({params:{start:0, limit:15}});
    }
```